# Problem with updating Angular CLI from version 11.2.13 to latest version on Mac

Tags: angular-cli

I know that there are a lot of advices according to my topic and I read them, used the recommended commands on Mac but I can not update my 11.2.13 CLI to 13 globally.

'ng --version' shows the following now:

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.13
Node: 16.14.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 
 ... 
 Ivy Workspace: 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1102.13 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         11.2.13 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   11.2.13 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          11.2.13 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.1102.13 (cli-only)
```

I tryed to use the following commands with sudo:

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest

The second command made files in my user account map and for a second it seemed that I successfully updated my CLI to 13 because 'ng --version' showed the following lines:

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.3
Node: 16.14.0
Package Manager: npm 8.3.1
OS: darwin x64

Angular: undefined
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1303.3
@angular-devkit/core         13.3.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   13.3.3
@angular/cli                 13.3.3
@schematics/angular          13.3.3
```

but when I deleted the files what were made by the '**npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest**' command it came back to CLI version 11.2.13 when I typed 'ng --version'.

Could you please recommend me a command or commands which helps me to update my CLI to version 13 globally and not just locally? How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was a brute force type...
Reinstalling macOS Catalina from scratch.
Installing latest Node.js, and after that the latest Angular CLI:

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.3
Node: 16.14.2
Package Manager: npm 8.5.0
OS: darwin x64
```

Now I have that I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Clean and install back maybe ?

```sh
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm i -g @angular/cli@13.3.3
```

Comment: I tryed it now but did not help, the Angular CLI version is still 11.2.13

Comment: Then the CLI is basing itself on your local package. Try leaving your folder (`cd ..`) then run the command again ?

Comment: I went back to the root directory and I tried to run the commands that you recommended, and after that I typed "ng --version'. The Angular CLI version is still the same (11.2.13). :/

Comment: an interesting thing when I typed the 'npm uninstall -g @angular/cli' command and I after that I asked 'ng --version' it still showed the Angular CLI version (11.2.13)

Comment: Are there maybe any compatibility issues regarding Angular version 13.3.3 and Node JS version 16.14.0?

Comment: Not that I know of, it seems that you have too many CLIs installed. Try removing all of your globally installed modules ?

Comment: How can I do that? If I tried to uninstall it but 'ng --version' always came up with the version 11.2.13